# one or more than one non-NA value in each of two groups of variables

Tags: r

I've got a data frame with two groups of variables, baseline variables (var1-var5) and follow-up variables (tar1-tar5), as well as an ID variable. This data frame also features some missingness.

I'd like to be able to get the count and proportion of all observations for which there is: both a value for **one or more than one of the var1-var5** variables **AND** for **one or more than one of the tar1-tar5** variables. In the below mwe, observations 02-06 but not observation 01 meet my criteria, and so I'd expect a count of 5 and a proportion of ~0.83.

The code I got for counts and proportions only gives me the observations for which there is no missingness for any of the variables, and I can't figure out how to change it. Any help would be much appreciated.

Starting point:

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c("01","02","03","04","05","06"),var1=c(NA,"a","a","a","a","a"),var2=c(NA,NA,"b","b","b","b"),var3=c(NA,NA,NA,"c","c","c"),var4=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,"d","d"),var5=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,"e"),tar1=c(NA,"a","a","a","a","a"),tar2=c(NA,NA,"b","b","b","b"),tar3=c(NA,NA,NA,"c","c","c"),tar4=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,"d","d"),tar5=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,"e"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Current code:

```
sum(!is.na(df$var1) & !is.na(df$var2) & !is.na(df$var3) & !is.na(df$var4) & !is.na(df$var5) & !is.na(df$tar1) & !is.na(df$tar2) & !is.na(df$tar3) & !is.na(df$tar4) & !is.na(df$tar5))   

sum(!is.na(df$var1) & !is.na(df$var2) & !is.na(df$var3) & !is.na(df$var4) & !is.na(df$var5) & !is.na(df$tar1) & !is.na(df$tar2) & !is.na(df$tar3) & !is.na(df$tar4) & !is.na(df$tar5))/nrow(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the description, it seems like we are looking for at least one 'var' that is non-NA and 'tar' as non-NA.  In that case, we can subset the dataset with 'var' columns, convert it to logical matrix (`!is.na(df[grep(...)])`), get the `rowSums` and check whether we have at least one non-NA elements i.e. `rowSums(...)>0`.  The same procedure is done with 'tar' subset of data, use the `&` to check whether both 'var' and 'tar' columns have a non-NA element

```
i1 <- rowSums(!is.na(df[grep("var", names(df))]))>0 &  
                   rowSums(!is.na(df[grep("tar", names(df))]))>0
i1
#[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE

sum(i1)
#[1] 5
mean(i1)
#[1] 0.8333333
```

Answer (score 0):

With a lot more words (which I always appreciate when I come back to my code six months later), but more generalizable: We make a function that returns a logical of which rows have at least some not NA.

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c("01","02","03","04","05","06"),var1=c(NA,"a","a","a","a","a"),var2=c(NA,NA,"b","b","b","b"),var3=c(NA,NA,NA,"c","c","c"),var4=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,"d","d"),var5=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,"e"),tar1=c(NA,"a","a","a","a","a"),tar2=c(NA,NA,"b","b","b","b"),tar3=c(NA,NA,NA,"c","c","c"),tar4=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,"d","d"),tar5=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,"e"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Does the actual work
whichRowsHaveValues <- function(dataFrame) {
  which <- apply(X=dataFrame, FUN=function(x) any(!is.na(x)), MARGIN=1)
  return(which)
}

# Choose columns
varCols <- grepl(x=colnames(df), pattern="var", fixed=TRUE)
tarCols <- grepl(x=colnames(df), pattern="tar", fixed=TRUE)

# Find the answer
goodRows <- whichRowsHaveValues(df[varCols]) & 
    whichRowsHaveValues(df[tarCols])
count <- sum(goodRows)
proportion <- count/nrow(df)
```

Of course, you may not want it *quite* so verbose, we don't really need all those intermediate variables. . . .